# Google Cloud ML Engine - Job failed due to an internal error . Can't execute a job

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

This is a ml-job I previously trained successfully  . But when I tried it today it's not working .

[image: My logs]

[image: Error Report]

So after that I tried removing all the things is the bucket and start over .  Still it's not working . Giving the following error .

> Internal error occurred. Please retry in a few minutes. If you still experience errors, contact Cloud ML.

Comment: A moderator deleted my answer because it is a duplicate, but SO won't let me de-dup the answer. To answer your question before the answer was deleted, did you run `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training my_job ... --region=us-east1` ?

Comment: Oh no. I will check with that and update you.

Comment: I just tried that and cloud console is reporting us-central1. Be sure to put the `--region` before any bare `--`.

Comment: Like this ? 

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_`date +%s`     --region us-central1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal Error on Google Cloud ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609471/internal-error-on-google-cloud-ml)

Comment: It's working thanks mate !