# Internal Error on Google Cloud ML

Tags: google-cloud-ml-engine

I am getting an error "Internal error occurred for the current attempt" while submitting a job on google cloud ML.

Can anyone help me on this ???
[image]

Comment: I also have the same .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609164/google-cloud-ml-engine-job-failed-due-to-an-internal-error-cant-execute-a-j

Comment: Did you try this on new job which means a brand-new project and a bucket ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it on new project and bucket. i believe it has something to do with google only. I think there servers are down. Not sure though

Comment: Yeah I tried everything .  Can you comment here when it works . I'll do the same .

Comment: Sure.By the time , I am thinking of running the job in a different region. You can try the same.

Comment: By creating a new project ?

Comment: No. Try within the same project.

Comment: Hi how to change the region in an existing project ?

Comment: when you are submitting a job, there would be one argument as region. Just put whatever region you want the job to run in.

Comment: can you kindly share a screen shot .

Comment: Hi how did it go?

Answer (score 2):

We're experiencing a bit of a capacity crunch making it a little hard to obtain VMs. You can try running in another region such as `us-east1` for the time being. We are working on making sure the error message is more informative. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: How can I change the region of the job. Can you please help me.

Comment: `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training my_job ... --region=us-east1`

Comment: Be sure to put `--region` *before* any bare `--` you might have.

Comment: So I have to put the region before any other arguments right ?

Comment: Before any of your *own* arguments. Here's a sample command-line: `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training us_east1 --region us-east1 --stream-logs --runtime-version 1.2 --job-dir ${GCS_JOB_DIR} --module-name trainer.task --package-path trainer/ -- --train-files $TRAIN_FILE                                     --eval-files $EVAL_FILE --train-steps $TRAIN_STEPS --eval-steps 100`